# Reusing OpenSSL SSL_CTX for multiple connections

Tags: openssl

Is it possible to reuse openssl `SSL_CTX` to connect to multiple servers.

```
SSL_CTX *ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_client_method());
```

and then I use it for multiple connections like this.

```
SSL *ssl = SSL_new(ssl_ctx);
```

This seems to be working fine but problem encountered when I am trying to use `SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback` which has to be invoked from each connection. However it takes ctx as parameter and it hence it overrides callback and the data passed to it.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you found an answer for this? Facing a similar issue.

Comment: @Martin, not so far, the only option is to create separate when using SSL_CTX_set_cert_verify_callback

Answer (score 0):

you can use `SSL_set_verify` for each connection.

```
void SSL_set_verify(SSL *s, int mode,
                    int (*verify_callback)(int, X509_STORE_CTX *));
```